# resize svg elements using scale property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am doing a little project. In that one i need to resize the element such as ellipse which i had drawn. I know we can resize the ellipse by tracking down the mousemove property like this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/9HXMG/) .

```
 function mouseMove(e) {}
```

But i am curious to know how it works when we use ***transfrom*** and  ***scale*** property for resizing of elements. I read some documentation works in w3.org in this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined) I am unable to understand how scale property can be applied, which involves some matrix transformations.

1. Please explain how to use scale and transform property to resize the elements by tracking mouse move with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example showing an ellipse changing size based on the mouse's current distance from the ellipse<strike>, without getting into matrices: https://jsfiddle.net/aaqs1wf0/</strike>: https://jsfiddle.net/aaqs1wf0/1/

SVG

```
<svg version="1.0" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200px" height="200px">
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="100" rx="20" ry="10"/>     
</svg>
```

<strike>Javascript</strike> (this contained unnecessarily adjusting of center, see update below)

```
var ellipse = document.getElementsByTagName("ellipse")[0];
var centerX = ellipse.getAttribute("cx");
var centerY = ellipse.getAttribute("cy");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  var x = event.clientX - centerX; // absolute distance from center
  if (x<0) x = x * -1;
  var y = event.clientY - centerY;
  if (y<0) y = y * -1;
  var scaleX = x/centerX; // proportional distance from center
  var scaleY = y/centerY;
  ellipse.setAttribute("cx", centerX/scaleX); // adjust the centers when adjusting scale so that it stays in one place.
  ellipse.setAttribute("cy", centerY/scaleY);
  ellipse.setAttribute("style","transform: scale(" + scaleX + ", " + scaleY + ")"); // scale the ellipse
});
```

**Updated JS** (which uses `transform-origin` to set center, and `matrix()`, as requested, though I think `scale()` still works)

```
var ellipse = document.getElementsByTagName("ellipse")[0];
var centerX = ellipse.getAttribute("cx");
var centerY = ellipse.getAttribute("cy");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  var x = event.clientX - centerX; // absolute distance from center
  if (x<0) x = x * -1;
  var y = event.clientY - centerY;
  if (y<0) y = y * -1;
  var scaleX = x/centerX; // proportional distance from center
  var scaleY = y/centerY;
  ellipse.setAttribute("style","transform: matrix(" + scaleX + ",0,0, " + scaleY + ",0,0); transform-origin: 100px 100px;"); // scale the ellipse
});
```

Basically, it takes the mouse's coordinates, compares it to the coordinates of the center of the ellipse, then scales it to the proportional difference.  Note that there's no built-in `function mouseMove()` (like in your link), but rather a `mousemove` event.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will you please let me know how to work the same of above using matrices? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To answer that, I'd have to know how transform matrices work, which I don't, hehe.

Comment: Was learning some matrix stuff this morning, so I updated my answer to use matrix (and also change the bad way I was centering the transform, which was escaping me the other day).